# when Tableviewcell height is variable then it is not calculating contentsize.height correctly

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I am using cell height for tableview is variable means different height for different cells.
I am using below code for finding bottom of tableview but it is always returning result false as I am going to end of tableview instead of true.

I am writing below code in deceleration event and using this for pagging when I come to bottom of tableview I want to do paging.

```cs
tableView.ContentOffset.Y >= (tableView.ContentSize.Height - tableView.Frame.Size.Height)
```

how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if (scrollView == _table) {
        if (scrollView.contentOffset.y + scrollView.frame.size.height > scrollView.contentSize.height) {

    }
}
```

My code works.

Comment: The code provided by me and you are same but it is not working when tableviewcell size is variable.